# Glasses shape design with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, shapes, css-shapes

I need to code this glasses shape design for the home page of a website with CSS, and I need to consider in the empty space of upside of glasses we want to put some dynamic data.
My problem is how to manage the **curve line** between two sides.
So far I have code the top circle with its pointer (however not perfectly) with CSS border and vh/vw for responsive purposes, I tried to use images for the curve part but it wasn't efficient because in the responsive version it won't work perfectly.

So I am looking for a code based approach to handle this section, any idea?

You can see the code below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;700&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  body {
    font-size: 12px
  }
}

.homePageHeader {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffff;
  height: 20vh;
}

.homePageWrapper {
  background: #FFF3D3 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  transition: .4s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.homePageCircleWrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 70vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.homePageCircleWrapperInner {
  height: 30vw;
  width: 30vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2.1875em solid #ff692814;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.homePageCircleHeading {
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.7em;
  color: #C86102;
}

.homePageCircleHeading h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.homePageCircleAppstores img:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 1.25em;
}

.homePageCircleImage {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

#circleScroll {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30vw;
  width: 30vw;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.homePageCircleImage img {
  width: 25vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.scrollPointer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2.5em;
  /* height: 35px; */
  background: #ff692814;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 47%;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -5.5em;
  border-top-right-radius: 2.5em;
  border-top-left-radius: 2.5em;
  height: 3.3em;
}

.homePageHeaderLogo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .4s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.homePageHeader {
  color: #81621F;
}

.homePageHeaderCTA {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.625em;
}

.homePageHeaderMenu {
  font-size: 0.625em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.homePageFooter {
  padding: 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vh;
  position: relative;
}

.homePageFooter span {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(129, 98, 31, 1);
}

.homePageFooter span:first-child {
  margin-right: 1.8em
}

.homePageFooterInside a {
  /* color: #ffff; */
  color: #CFCFCF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="homePageWrapper">
  <div class="custom-footer"></div>

  <div class="homePageHeader">
    <div class="homePageHeaderMenu">
      <p>MENU </p>
    </div>
    <div class="homePageHeaderLogo">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="homePageHeaderCTA">
      <p>Click here
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="homePageCircleWrapper">
    <div class="homePageCircleWrapperInner">
      <div class="homePageOptions">

        <div id="circleScroll">
          <span class="scrollPointer"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="homePageCircleHeading">
        <h1>
          A website
          <br><strong>For you</strong>
        </h1>

      </div>

      <div class="homePageCircleAppstores">

        <span>span</span> <span>span</span></br>
        <span>span</span> <span>span</span>
      </div>
      <div class="homePageCircleImage">

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="homePageFooter">

      <div class="homePageFooterInside">
        <a href=""><span>Question</span></a>
        <a href=""> <span>Answer</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

## Design:

[image]

Comment: Why didn't using an image work? An SVG for example, would be small, efficient and precise, and could be resized to whatever size needed.

Comment: Yeah, SVG is cool for responsive, BUT the problem is that in the responsive version the image won't attach in the circle very good, while resizing some spaces or overlap shows up

Comment: You're going to need to be a little more specific with this issue about SVG. Its just that trying to use CSS for this seems overkill. I feel an alternative like SVG would probably be a better place to start. "the image", "the circle", "some spaces" - more elaboration on what went wrong would be a good start :)

Comment: Have you tried combinations of linear and radial gradients?

Comment: Ok, let me try one more time :) 
If you check the code right now, I build a circle with border-width: 2.1875em,
If I want to use SVG, I need to use a separate div and set it to the background image and with the absolute position, I will need to connect the image to the top circle. correct? 
Now, if I positioned it with vw/vh it will dynamically change the size, but depends on the viewports I will have different spaces and it won't be fit, please check this image, you will understand what I mean:

https://ibb.co/4FGNG4J

Comment: @AHaworth I tried but it wasn't useful for me, or I am don't have enough experience to make a good shape with these properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated my question. Now it looks like glasses. Is this what you wanted?

If you want to move the glasses then you can use the class `container`

```css
.firstHandle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  background: gray;
  margin-left: 5.1em;
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}

.firstCircle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 20px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.curve {
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 200px;
    border-top-right-radius: 200px;
    border: 15px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.secondCircle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 20px solid grey;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 10000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.secondHandle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background: gray;
  margin-left: 5.1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="firstHandle"></div>

  <div class="firstCircle">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="curve"></div>

  <div class="secondCircle">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="secondHandle"></div>

</div>
```

Let me know if you want me to change anything else.

Comment: Yeah something like that, but I couldn't manage to style it exactly like the curve connector one in between two circles

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: Thank you a lot man, yes that's what I need,  the only thing is that the border color has 0.4 opacity and it will expose the overlap of each object so I need to find a way to fix that, I changed the sizes to dynamic vw and it works very well

Comment: That's great! i can make the border color with an opacity of 0.4 if you want

Comment: Thank you, but what is your solution for the overlapping between curve and border?

Comment: We should use "rgba" instead of grey. Like  `rgba(128,128,128, 0.4);`. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to draw this using just CSS gradients. That way it can be used as a background-image on any element as required, no need for extra HTML or SVGs.

Here is a class called frame - obviously the percentages can be tweaked get the exact proportions required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.frame {
  
  --actualh: 100vh; /* set this to what you want the height of the whole thing to be */
  --bg: #6a6a6a; /* background color */
  --frame: #838383; /* frame color */
  
 /* These are measurements taken from the image given. They will be used relatively to calculate various dimensions */ 
  --w: 11.7;
  --h: 26.7;
  
  background-color: var(--bg);
  width: calc(calc(var(--w) / var(--h)) * var(--actualh));
  height: var(--actualh);
  
  background-image:
   /* the lower lens */
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 75%, var(--frame) 0%, var(--frame) 27%, transparent 27%, transparent 100%),
   /* the upper lens */
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 25%, var(--bg) 0%, var(--bg) 23%, var(--frame) 23%, var(--frame) 27%, transparent 27%, transparent 100%),
   /* the bridge curved part */
   linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 70%, var(--bg) 70%, var(--bg) 100%),
   radial-gradient(circle, var(--bg) 0%, var(--bg) 23.93%, var(--frame) 23.93%, var(--frame) 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 100%),
   /* the ears */
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 4%, transparent 0%, transparent 5%, var(--bg) 5%, var(--bg) 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 100%),
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 96%, transparent 0%, transparent 5%, var(--bg) 5%, var(--bg) 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 100%),
   linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, var(--frame) 40%, var(--frame) 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame"></div>
```